# Как выполнить функцию один раз при скролле до опредленного блока

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Есть лэндинг, при скролле до определенного блока мы меняем hash, НО
функция срабатывает при скроле и хэш меняется даже прис скроле в один пиксель
ВОПРОС: Как сделать так, чтобы это происходило лишь один раз?

```
    let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");

const addActiveClass = () => {
    let fromTop = window.scrollY + 280;

    navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
        let section = document.querySelector(navLink.hash);

        if (section.offsetTop <= fromTop && section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight > fromTop) {
            navLink.classList.add("nav__link--active");

            if (history.replaceState) {
                history.pushState(null, null, navLink.hash);
            } else {
                location.hash = navLink.hash;
            }
        } else {
            navLink.classList.remove("nav__link--active");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- За приделами функции addActiveClass хранить предыдущее значение
- каждый раз при вычислении сверять с предыдущим и если изменилось то добавлять в history и менять классы

Comment: сможете подсказать примером кода?

Comment: let prevState;
addActiveClass() => {
  ...
  if (navLink.hash !== prevState){
    prevState = location.hash = navLink.hash;  
  }
}